# Why $(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)(2\pi i\xi)^\beta e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi}=(\partial _x)^\beta [(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)]e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Why
$$(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)(2\pi i\xi)^\beta e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi}=(\partial _x)^\beta [(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)]e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi} ?$$

Indeed, to prove that the fourier transform is in the Schwarz space, we do as following
\begin{align*}
(2\pi i\xi)^\beta (i\partial _\xi)^\alpha \hat f(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)(2i\pi i\xi)^\beta e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^n}(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)(-\partial _x)^\beta  e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}dx\\
&\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{\mathbb R^n}(\partial _x)^\beta [(2\pi x)^\alpha f(x)]e^{-2i\pi x\cdot \xi}dx
\end{align*}
but I don't understand the equality $(*)$. I recall that $\alpha,\beta  \in \mathbb N^n$ and that we used
$$x^\alpha =\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha _i}.$$

Comment: Are you sure $x^\alpha = \sum_i x_i^{\alpha_i}$ and not $x^\alpha = x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$?

Comment: @Neal: For sure you right :) I corrected it.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: It wasn't me, but the downvote may be because the equation you ask about is pretty obviously false; one side involves derivatives of $f$ while the other side doesn't. Showing the Fourier transform maps the Schwarz space to itself isn't deep or all that hard but it's slightly trickier than the above. Gotta go now...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: If you are inetrested, here is the proof of my course (proposition 2.1). There is maybe a subtlety I don't see. Thanks, http://jahia-prod.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/pde/files/cours/2015-2016/harmonic%20analysis/Lecture4.pdf

Comment: Oh. The equation in the title of your post is nonsense. But equality (*) above is just integration by parts.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Very good, I see now. Thank you very much.